# Eclipse inactive debug point

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I have a maven project, using spring. Debug point is not getting applied on any of the Java classes, this is the code shown in debug mode:

[image]

There is not tail generated on the circle, I have some jars, their code I am able to debug, below is the screen:

[image]

I have cleaned up the project, deleted and created new tomcat. I can see the .class file present in WEB-INF/classes. This is the deployment assembly:

[image]

If I try to call the endpoint I get 404. Any suggestions are appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For me issue was the package that contained controller java file was missing from component-scan package declaration, so controller was not deployed on tomcat.